# Installing Ubuntu in a secondary HDD, without formatting the drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have an SSD with Windows and an HDD with some important large folders in it. How can I install Ubuntu in the HDD without losing those files? Can I make the required partitioning from Windows or do I have to do it while installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Disk Management` in Windows, in order to Shrink you HDD. After shrinking you will be left with some un-allocated space. That will be the new partition of yours in which you can install Ubuntu. You can also do that during the installation of the Ubuntu.

If you don't want to use Linux, accommodated in first level by the hardware of your machine, you should consider Virtualization. You won't have to dual boot and you will have the ability to access Linux, from within Windows. (e.g. Virtual Box)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I thought about virtualization but I think I want to dual-boot. I want to use Linux as the main OS (since after years of programming it's becoming a struggle to survive without it) and use Windows only for games and other software.

Comment: Windows has come a long way in the support it provides for developers. You can even install Ubuntu through the Windows store. Consider giving it a a try because Dual Booting has it's ups and downs.

Comment: Maybe Windows has, but a huge amount of software libraries have Linux has the priority OS. Still, I will research it more before making the decision, thank you for your input!